# Loki doesn't see my GTX1070

Tags: release-loki, nvidia

It seems that Loki can't see my discrete GPU (Nvidia GTX1070). Here's the output from a couple of useful commands I've seen listed while trying to debug this.

```
$ inxi -Gx
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA Device 1b81 bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.3 drivers: fbdev (unloaded: vesa) FAILED: nouveau
           Resolution: 1024x768@76.00hz
           GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.8, 256 bits)
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0 Direct Rendering: Yes
$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1b81 (rev a1)
```

I have tried installing the 370 drivers several times. I always get a black screen upon reboot. Here is the sequence I've tried many times:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-370
sudo reboot
```

After reboot, I get a black screen. I then purge the nvidia driver and reboot into omfg low-resolution mode (purgatory?). My monitor is 4K and I'd like to use those pixels...

Loki is also unable to identify my LG monitor.

[image: System Settings >> Displays]

Is there some "proper" means of installing the Nvidia 370+ drivers?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with UEFI Secure Boot. I have an ASUS motherboard. I booted into BIOS and then disabled Secure Boot. To install the latest driver I used,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-370
sudo reboot
```

and then everything was perfect!